Copying fur groom to another character?
I made a character and used Quick Fur to add fur, then I used the sculpt window to groom the fur and make some hairs longer than others. Now I want to copy the hair exactly as it is to a new identical character. Copying modifiers worked but I can't find a way to copy the sculpt, is it possible?

you can copy the curves with Geometry Nodes. Just output the geometry of the source curves. Then apply to modifier to the (target) curves object. After that, you need to attach the curves to the surface (Sculpt mode, menu Curves > Snap to Nearest Surface). If the models are very different it will hopefully look similar but it won't look 100% identical.

Thanks! novice here, how do I output the geometry of the source curve? are there any video tutorials for this?

Oh, I forgot one step. You have to deal with the modifiers or they will be copied as applied. I will post an example...

You can copy the curves with a Geometry Nodes modifier. Here is an example:

the cube got a Curves > Fur added. It's same as Quick Effects > Fur
while Suzanne the monkey head has an Curves > Empty Hair object.
both models require a UV map with no overlapping UV islands

To copy the hair curves:


select the source curves object
and disable all modifiers in the viewport so we can copy the unmodified original curves



select the target curves object

add a new Geometry Nodes modifier to Suzsanne's Curves (target)

the Geometry Nodes modifier just outputs the geometry of the source curves with an Object Info node. You can drag and drop the Cube's Curves from the outliner into the node editor. Blender then creates the node for you.

note that the Geometry Nodes modifier Surface Deform now displays an error message. We'll fix this soon.

apply the Geometry Nodes modifier to make the copy permanent by using the modifier's dropdown menu > Apply, or by pressing Ctrl+A while the mouse pointer hovers the modifier.




now we need to attach the curves to the surface. This is done in Sculpt mode
select the menu item Curves > Snap to Nearest Surface to attach the curves to the model
the error of the Surface Deform GN modifier should be gone now



finally, enable the modifiers of the Cube's Curves again, copy them (Ctrl+L in Object mode) and make sure the settings in the target curves object are correct (Surface object and UV Map).

The hair style will not look 100% identical, but similar, depending on how similar the models are. For comparision, I've added a cylinder.

Thank you so much!
